# ResEdit x64 Winapi deleting manually created IDs

Tags: winapi, resources, editor

I am using ResEdit x64 to create dialog boxes and resources. But when I want to manually add a resource myself like a button, and then I edit say, another dialog box with resedit, and then I save the file, the resedit deletes the ID that i manually created.

Is it possible to use resedit to edit my main window? Ive only seen options for dialog boxes.

Anyone suggest a solution to this, or another free resource editor?